# should virtual hosts be defined as CNAME in DNS server?

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost, cname

Apache doc regarding virtual hosts states:

`Your server has a single IP address, and multiple aliases (CNAMES) point to this machine in DNS. You want to run a web server for www.example.com and www.example.org on this machine.`

Am I right to assume that I can also bind two domains to this single IP address using A DNS records, instead of creating one A record and CNAME record for another domain pointing to the first domain? I mean that it won't affect Apache's functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct.  The browser passes the name it is requesting.  It does not care what type of DNS record was used to resolve the name to an ip address.

I usually use Cnames though for the actual domain.  and point it at an a record that just represents the ip.  Just a way to organize things and make it easier in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide example on this _I usually use Cnames though for the actual domain. and point it at an a record that just represents the ip._ ?

Comment: I mean something like:  ipaddrmainweb1  A  10.23.1.98   then point the cnames at ipaddrmainweb1.  If you have the virtualhosts clumped together you can move them around by just changing the ip that ipaddrmainweb1 resolves to.  You can also group virtual hosts by machine so they can be tracked in one more way.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/260254/what-does-the-ttl-on-a-cname-record-mean  is some more info.